# android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0

Tags: android, database-cursor

I am using custom adapter extending cursor adapter for displaying data in listview, to display particular phone number i have passed the id to a method in database class but it is showing

```
errorandroid.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
```

while placing debugger in the the method it is not going after the line

```
num = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("ContactNumber"));
```

Can any one help me to solve it.
This is the code:

```
public String getNumberFromId(int id) 
{
    String num;
    db= this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.query(scheduletable, new String[] { "ContactNumber" },"_id="+id, null, null, null, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    num = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("ContactNumber")); 
    cursor.close();
    db.close();
    return num;
}
```

Answer (score 116):

Whenever you are dealing with Cursors, ALWAYS check for null and check for `moveToFirst()` without fail.

```
if( cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst() ){
    num = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("ContactNumber"));
    cursor.close(); 
}
```

Place logs appropriately to see whether it is returning `null` or an empty cursor. According to that check your query.

**Update** Put both the checks in a single statement as mentioned by Jon in the comment below.

**Update 2** Put the `close()` call within the valid cursor scope.

Comment: its wrong, if cursors is null and you make a close on this cursor, you become a NPE

Comment: I have no clue how I missed it back then. Good catch. Thanks!

Comment: this code is working for me... I did want xactly that.

Comment: If `cursor != null` is true, but `cursor.movetofirst()` is false, `cursor.close()` will not get reached.  Seems like you would still want to close the cursor in this case, and this is bad practice?  Unless `moveToFirst()` always returns true?

Answer (score 23):

try this.. this will avoid an Exception being thrown when the cursor is empty..

```
if(cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()){
    num = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("ContactNumber")); 
    cursor.close();
}
```

Comment: this code is working for me... I did want xactly that.

Comment: This code will crash on cursor.close() if cursor is null.

Comment: @AkashAgarwal It is similar to checking the count is greater than to zero. Just have to make sure cursor is not null too. `if(cursor != null && cursor.getCount()!= 0)`

Answer (score 13):

First check this Condition before fetching data

```
if(cursor!=null && cursor.getCount()>0){
  cursor.moveToFirst();
  num = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("ContactNumber")); 
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Check the return value from `moveToFirst()`, before you try to read anything from the cursor. It looks as if no results are being returned.

Answer (score 5):

a save schema to query `Cursor`s is

```
// just one
Cursor cursor = db.query(...);
if (cursor != null) {
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        value = cursor.getSomething();
    }
    cursor.close();
}

// multiple columns
Cursor cursor = db.query(...);
if (cursor != null) {
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        values.add(cursor.getSomething());
    }
    cursor.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In case people are still looking:

Instead of searching for `"ContactNumber"` try searching for `Phone.NUMBER`. The tutorial has the code with more details: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html

Answer (score 0):

try to uninstall the app and then again test it... actually the sqlite db is created only once when the app is first install... so if you think your logic is current then reinstalling the app will do the trick for you. !!!!