# CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0 happens when record is deleted

Tags: android, database

A i understand in something with a cursor, but i can't figure out a solution for my own. So I need your help.
And it happens only when a delete a record. On DisplayContact.java in line 65.

Here is my class files.

**DisplayContact.java**

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class DisplayContact extends Activity {

     int from_Where_I_Am_Coming = 0;
       private DBHelper mydb ;
       TextView name ;
       TextView note;
       int id_To_Update = 0;

       Button btnDel;

       String formattedDate;
       TextView txtView;
       SimpleDateFormat date;
       Calendar c;

//     TextView dosage;
//     TextView day;

       @Override
       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_contact);

          name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editTextName);
          note = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editTextNote);

          btnDel = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonDelete);

          mydb = new DBHelper(this);

          c = Calendar.getInstance();
          date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
          formattedDate = date.format(c.getTime());
          txtView = new TextView(this);

          Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras(); 
          if(extras !=null)
          {
             int Value = extras.getInt("id");
             if(Value>0){
                //means this is the view part not the add contact part.
                Cursor rs = mydb.getData(Value);
                id_To_Update = Value;
                rs.moveToFirst();
                String nam = rs.getString(rs.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.CONTACTS_COLUMN_NAME));
                String not = rs.getString(rs.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.CONTACTS_COLUMN_NOTE));
                String cd = rs.getString(rs.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.CONTACTS_COLUMN_DATE));

                if (!rs.isClosed()) {
                   rs.close();
                }

                name.setText((CharSequence)nam);
                note.setText((CharSequence)not);
                txtView.setText(formattedDate);            
               }
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
               OnClickListener listenerDel = new OnClickListener() {
                   public void onClick(View v) {

                    mydb.deleteContact(id_To_Update);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Deleted Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),com.example.database3.MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                   }

               };

               btnDel.setOnClickListener(listenerDel);
          }
       }
       @Override
       public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
          // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
          Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras(); 
          if(extras !=null)
          {
             int Value = extras.getInt("id");
             if(Value>0){
                getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.display_contact, menu);
             }
             else{
                getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.mainmenu, menu);
             }
          }
          return true;
       }

       public void run(View view)
       {    
          Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
          if(extras !=null)
          {
             int Value = extras.getInt("id");
             if(Value>0){
                if(mydb.updateContact(id_To_Update,name.getText().toString(),         
                    note.getText().toString(),
                    txtView.getText().toString())){

                       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Updated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();   
                       Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),com.example.database3.MainActivity.class);
                       startActivity(intent);
                }       
                else{
                   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "not Updated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();   
                }
             }
             else{
                if(mydb.insertContact(name.getText().toString(),
                    note.getText().toString(),
                    txtView.getText().toString())){
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();    
                }       
                else{
                   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "not done", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  
                }
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),com.example.database3.MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
             }
          }
       }
       @Override 
       public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) { 
          super.onOptionsItemSelected(item); 

          switch(item.getItemId()){ 
             case R.id.item1: 
                Bundle dataBundle = new Bundle();
                dataBundle.putInt("id", 0);
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),com.example.database3.DisplayContact.class);
                intent.putExtras(dataBundle);
                startActivity(intent);

                  Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

                     int Value = extras.getInt("id");
                     if(Value>0){
                        if(mydb.updateContact(id_To_Update,name.getText().toString(), 
                            note.getText().toString(),
                            txtView.getText().toString())){
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Updated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  
                         }      
                        else{
                           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "not Updated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();   
                        }
                     }
                     else{
                        if(mydb.insertContact(name.getText().toString(),
                            note.getText().toString(),
                            txtView.getText().toString())){
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();    
                        }       
                    else{
                       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "not done", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  
                    }
                     }
            finish();
            return true; 
            default: 
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item); 
           } 
       } 

       @Override
       public boolean onKeyDown(int keycode, KeyEvent event) {
              if (keycode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
                 Intent a = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
                 a.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                 startActivity(a);
                 return true;
              }
              return super.onKeyDown(keycode, event);
           }
    }
```

**DBHelper.java**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
//import java.util.HashMap;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.DatabaseUtils;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {


       public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "MyDBName.db";
       public static final String CONTACTS_TABLE_NAME = "contacts";
       public static final String CONTACTS_COLUMN_ID = "id";
       public static final String CONTACTS_COLUMN_NAME = "name";
       public static final String CONTACTS_COLUMN_NOTE = "note";
       public static final String CONTACTS_COLUMN_DATE = "date";

//     private HashMap hp;

       public DBHelper(Context context) {
          super(context, DATABASE_NAME , null, 1);
       }

       @Override
       public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
          // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          db.execSQL(
                  "create table contacts " +
                  "(id integer primary key," +
                  " name text," +
                  " note text," +
                  " date text)"
                  );
       }

       @Override
       public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
          // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS contacts");
          onCreate(db);
       }

       public boolean insertContact  (String name, String note, String date) {
          SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
          ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();

          contentValues.put("name", name);
          contentValues.put("date", date);  
          contentValues.put("note", note);

          db.insert("contacts", null, contentValues);
          return true;
       }
       public Cursor getData(int id){
          SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
          Cursor res =  db.rawQuery( "select * from contacts where id="+id+"", null );
          return res;
       }

       public int numberOfRows(){
          SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
          int numRows = (int) DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(db, CONTACTS_TABLE_NAME);
          return numRows;
       }

       public boolean updateContact (Integer id, String name, String note, String date){

          SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
          ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
          contentValues.put("name", name);
          contentValues.put("note", note);
          contentValues.put("date", date);
          db.update("contacts", contentValues, "id = ? ", new String[] { Integer.toString(id) } );
          return true;
       }

       public Integer deleteContact (Integer id){
          SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
          return db.delete("contacts", 
          "id = ? ", 
          new String[] { Integer.toString(id) });
       }

       public ArrayList <String> getAllCotacts(){

          ArrayList<String> array_list = new ArrayList<String>();
          //hp = new HashMap();
          SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
          Cursor res =  db.rawQuery( "select * from contacts", null );
          res.moveToFirst();
          while(res.isAfterLast() == false){
          array_list.add(res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(CONTACTS_COLUMN_DATE)) + "    " + res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(CONTACTS_COLUMN_NAME)));
          res.moveToNext();
          }
       return array_list;
       }
    }
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
       public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.database3.MESSAGE";

       private ListView obj;    
       DBHelper mydb;

       @Override
       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

          mydb = new DBHelper(this);
          ArrayList <String> array_list = mydb.getAllCotacts();

          ArrayAdapter <String> arrayAdapter = new  ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, array_list);

          //adding it to the list view.
          obj = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
          obj.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

          obj.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){

         @Override
         public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
         long arg3) {
             // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             int id_To_Search = arg2 + 1;
             Bundle dataBundle = new Bundle();
             dataBundle.putInt("id", id_To_Search);
             Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),com.example.database3.DisplayContact.class);
             intent.putExtras(dataBundle);
             startActivity(intent);
         }
         });
       }
       @Override
       public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
          // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
          getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.mainmenu, menu);
          return true;
          }
       @Override 
       public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){ 

          super.onOptionsItemSelected(item); 
          switch(item.getItemId()) 
          { 
             case R.id.item1: 
                Bundle dataBundle = new Bundle();
                dataBundle.putInt("id", 0);
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),com.example.database3.DisplayContact.class);
                intent.putExtras(dataBundle);
                startActivity(intent);
                return true; 
             default: 
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item); 

           } 

       } 
       public boolean onKeyDown(int keycode, KeyEvent event) {
          if (keycode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
             moveTaskToBack(true);
          }
          return super.onKeyDown(keycode, event);
       }

    }
```

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10244222/android-database-cursorindexoutofboundsexception-index-0-requested-with-a-size

Comment: if (!rs.isClosed()) is the having the error check whether it exist or is null

Comment: Try `Cursor res =  db.rawQuery( "select * from contacts where id="+id+"", null ); if(res.moveToFirst()) return res;else return null;` in `getData`

Comment: OnClickListener listenerDel = new OnClickListener() {
                   public void onClick(View v) {

                    mydb.deleteContact(id_To_Update);rs.close();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Deleted Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),com.example.database3.MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                   }

               };

Comment: you have to close the cursor after deleting the data rs.close().

Comment: you have to close the cursor after deleting the data rs.close().

and how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

i think your rs returns 0 so try this code

```
 Cursor rs = mydb.getData(Value);

    if (rs != null && rs.moveToFirst()) {

        rs.moveToFirst();
            for (int i = 0; i < rs.getCount(); i++) {

                String nam = rs.getString(rs.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.CONTACTS_COLUMN_NAME));
                        String not = rs.getString(rs.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.CONTACTS_COLUMN_NOTE));
                        String cd = rs.getString(rs.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.CONTACTS_COLUMN_DATE));

                cur.moveToNext();

            }
        }
    }

} catch (Exception e) {

    e.printStackTrace();

} finally {
    if ( mydb != null) {
        mydb.close();
        mydb = null;
    }

    if (rs != null) {
        rs.close();
        rs = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Now i am having this kind of error: at this line:
String nam = rs.getString(rs.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.CONTACTS_COLUMN_NAME));
E/AndroidRuntime(3793): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.database3/com.example.database3.DisplayContact}:android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
E/AndroidRuntime(3793):Caused by: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
08-18 17:30:37.059: E/AndroidRuntime(3793): at com.example.database3.DisplayContact.onCreate(DisplayContact.java:63)

Comment: i think that the probem is with deleting. Cause on Delete button press, DB is updated, but not a ListView in MainActivity.java
i am working with this example:
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_sqlite_database.htm

Comment: it navigates me to mainActivity, but as you press on list lement (info on listeElement is showed by -1position)it shows me an error.

Comment: can you send me a zip file of your project ?