# error show cursor out of bound

Tags: android, sqlite

i'm show the particular data into listview bt it doenot show anything even my emulator goes blank.... 
the query is as..

```
SQLiteDatabase sd = db.getReadableDatabase();
        String select = "SELECT * FROM pending_dues_table WHERE _pending_dues_id ="+i;
        cr = sd.rawQuery(select, null);
         if (cr != null) {
                //cr.moveToFirst();
             int ii;
             ii=cr.getColumnIndex("pending_dues_notice");
                while (cr.moveToLast()){                    
                    namelist.add(cr.getString(ii));
                    //studentno.add(cursor.getString(1));                   
                }
            }      
        ArrayList<String>combimelist=new ArrayList<String>();
        for(int j = 0; j<namelist.size();j++){
            combimelist.add(namelist.get(j));
        }
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(StudentDues.this,R.layout.student_due, combimelist);
```

and locat show error as..

```
05-25 03:33:56.225: E/AndroidRuntime(5134): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-25 03:33:56.225: E/AndroidRuntime(5134): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: [memory exhausted]
05-25 03:33:56.225: E/AndroidRuntime(5134):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Your cursor is empty `CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0` Which means, the size of the cursor is zero and you are requesting the index 0. Chenge `
        `if(CR.moveToFirst()){` to `if(CR != null && CR.moveToFirst(){`

Comment: Do as I suggested, check if the cursor is null and if the first position is accessible before traversing your cursor. I would also suggest using SQLite DB browser to check your database and a lot of stuff you can do with that.

Comment: still show same error

Comment: You are doing something wrong, check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10244222/android-database-cursorindexoutofboundsexception-index-0-requested-with-a-size). What is the line number 57 in your code above?

Comment: its another class which get rollno to show data and line 57 call the method getrollno of dadabase class

Comment: if (get_rollno.equals(CR.getString(0)))

Comment: I cant see that line in the code you have posted above.

Comment: its iin another activity with name TeacherStudent.java

Comment: public void onClick(View v){get_rollno=GET_ROLLNO.getText().toString(); DataHelperStudent db=new DataHelperStudent(ctx); db.open(); Cursor CR=db.getRollNo(db); boolean loginstatus = false; String NAME = ""; if(CR != null && CR.moveToFirst()){ do{if (get_rollno.equals(CR.getString(0))) {loginstatus = true; NAME=CR.getString(0);} }while(CR.moveToNext());}if(loginstatus) {Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "login success Welcome "+NAME , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); Intent teach_action=new Intent(TeacherStudent.this,Teacher_Student_Detail.class); startActivity(teach_action); }

Comment: else {
     Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "login failed---- "+NAME , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     }   
   }
  });

Answer (score 1):

Your logcat says

```
    CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
       ......
    at com.example.mytryapp.TeacherStudent$1.onClick(TeacherStudent.java:57)
```

so i think your problem is hare

```
if (get_rollno.equals(CR.getString(0))) 
{
   loginstatus = true; NAME=CR.getString(0);
}
```

and my suggestion is just check before call it that you must have some data. 
try to do this Hope it works

```
if(cursor.getCount() > 0){
// get values from cursor here
    if (get_rollno.equals(CR.getString(0))) 
    {
       loginstatus = true; NAME=CR.getString(0);
    }
}
```

or there is better way

try

```
Cursor cursor = //query here
while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
    // retrieve  values from the cursor
}
```

if there is any problem ... comment it

Comment: now its doesn't show error but show login filed toast only

Comment: that means if (get_rollno.equals(CR.getString(0)))  returns false , thats why you loginstatus is still false..

Comment: there is another kind of problem i found all data from database automatically deleted

Comment: what i do to stop this??

Comment: if this solution solve this error then you need to accept it otherwise it shows as unanswered

Comment: i think that is another issue..... normally it's not possible to automatically delete data. raise another question..and let me know

Comment: i have problem with sqliteopenhelper class..... its not create two table within one database in same class