# android sqlite query not working but does in real mysql table

Tags: android, sqlite

I got the following sql query:

```
SELECT _id, librust from vorgaenge_list WHERE _id = some number;
```

I tested it in a table identical to the android one with xampp MySQL and it returns one line with the desired id.

Now in android I use this line:

```
Cursor cursor1 = database.rawQuery("SELECT " + VorgangDbHelper.COLUMN_ID + ", " + VorgangDbHelper.COLUMN_LEFTB + " FROM " + VorgangDbHelper.TABLE_VORGAENGE_LIST + " WHERE " + VorgangDbHelper.COLUMN_ID + " = " + deleteId,null);
```

I logged my database entries and there is an entry with an ID matching my deleteId variable, so it definetely must return one row.

also tried it with using `selectionargs` but still the same.

The log says:

```
D/Cursor1: =android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@434ef288
```

and gives an exception at `cursor1.moveToFirst();`

```
android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
```

Do I miss something in my query?

Comment: Your query is correct. Only, that it returns no record  (`with a size of 0`) for that id.

Comment: But why is that? My Column `VorgangDbHelper.COLUMN_LEFTB` contains a String ?!

Comment: Try this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10244222/android-database-cursorindexoutofboundsexception-index-0-requested-with-a-size

Comment: Check the value of `deleteId`. What you are probably doing (I'm just guessing by experience, since you didn't pose much code) is that you are associating the **position** in a ListView as the **id** in the table. Which is completely wrong.

Comment: `D/deleteID-Int: =19` and the matching entry: `D/VorgangDataSource: ID: 19, Inhalt: 19.06.2016 09:41 | 09:41 | linke Brust`

Comment: @Lonnie: my deleteId is calculated by getting the first ID of the table and then adding the listview position-ID

Comment: `my deleteId is calculated by getting the first ID of the table and then adding the listview position-ID` And this is **wrong**: ListView positions are never related to table ids. You can't rely on that. When items are deleted in the table, you'll be left with **holes** in the numbering. So they are no longer consequential.

Comment: So what do you suggest?

Comment: Google for `android listview database crud`

Comment: Ok I' ll try that and give you a feedback if it worked

Comment: Well I googled your phrase and in those examples I found they used the listview position ID to delete database entries. That´s what I do now, so I don´t know what I should change.