# Saving elements in SQLite Android

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, cursor

I want to save `DatabaseTableDay` to my SQLite in anndroid applicatin but something gones wrong.

My `DatabaseDAODay` is:

```
public class DatabaseDAODay {

    public static final String TAG = "DaysDAO";

    // Database fields
    private SQLiteDatabase mDatabase;
    private DatabaseHelper mDbHelper;
    private Context mContext;
    private String[] mAllColumns = { DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_DAY_ID,
            DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_DAY_NAME, DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_DAY_WEIGHT};

    public DatabaseDAODay(Context context) {
        this.mContext = context;
        mDbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
        // open the database
        try {
            open();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "SQLException on openning database " + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void open() throws SQLException {
        mDatabase = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    public void close() {
        mDbHelper.close();
    }

    public DatabaseTableDay createDay(String name, float weight, Long id) {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_DAY_NAME, name);
        values.put(DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_DAY_WEIGHT, weight);
        long insertId = id;
        Cursor cursor = mDatabase.query(DatabaseHelper.TABLE_DAYS, mAllColumns,
                DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_DAY_ID + " = " + insertId, null, null,
                null, null);
        DatabaseTableDay newDay = new DatabaseTableDay();
        if(cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()){
            newDay = cursorToDay(cursor);
            cursor.close();
            Toast.makeText(mContext,"im here",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        return newDay;
    }



    public void deleteDay(DatabaseTableDay databaseTableDay) {
        long id = databaseTableDay.getId();
        // delete all employees of this company
        DatabaseDAOActivity databaseDAOActivity = new DatabaseDAOActivity(mContext);
        List<DatabaseTableActivity> databaseTableActivities = databaseDAOActivity.getActivitiesOfDay(id);
        if (databaseTableActivities != null && !databaseTableActivities.isEmpty()) {
            for (DatabaseTableActivity e : databaseTableActivities) {
                databaseDAOActivity.deleteActivity(e);
            }
        }

        System.out.println("the deleted day has the id: " + id);
        mDatabase.delete(DatabaseHelper.TABLE_DAYS, DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_DAY_ID
                + " = " + id, null);
    }


    public List<DatabaseTableDay> getAllDays() {
        List<DatabaseTableDay> listDays = new ArrayList<DatabaseTableDay>();

        Cursor cursor = mDatabase.query(DatabaseHelper.TABLE_DAYS, mAllColumns,
                null, null, null, null, null);
        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
                DatabaseTableDay day = cursorToDay(cursor);
                listDays.add(day);
                cursor.moveToNext();
            }
            // make sure to close the cursor
            cursor.close();
        }
        return listDays;
    }


    public DatabaseTableDay getDayById(long id) {
        Cursor cursor = mDatabase.query(DatabaseHelper.TABLE_DAYS, mAllColumns,
                DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_DAY_ID + " = ?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }, null, null, null);
        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
        }

        DatabaseTableDay databaseTableDay = cursorToDay(cursor);
        return databaseTableDay;
    }

    protected DatabaseTableDay cursorToDay(Cursor cursor) {
        DatabaseTableDay databaseTableDay = new DatabaseTableDay();
        databaseTableDay.setId(cursor.getLong(0));
        databaseTableDay.setName(cursor.getString(1));
        databaseTableDay.setWeight(cursor.getLong(2));
        return databaseTableDay;
    }


}
```

and I try to save it by:

```
saveButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        DatabaseTableDay databaseTableDay = databaseDAODay.createDay(
                editText.getText().toString(), 100f, new Long(myId));

        List<DatabaseTableDay> list = databaseDAODay.getAllDays();
    }
});
```

but `list` is empty anyway.

Probably the problem is `createDay()` method in `DatabaseDAODay` because if condition is always null and application doesn' run `cursorToDay()` method.

I had problem without condition and if there was only `cursot.moveToFirst()` and then `cursorToDay()` there was `NullPoinerException` - because coursor was null. I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10244222/android-database-cursorindexoutofboundsexception-index-0-requested-with-a-size) and put condition `!=null` but actually nothing happens and List is always empty...

How should I solve my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right about the problem being `createDay()`: instead of inserting a new day by using `insert()` you try to read from the database by using `query()`

Change your method like this:

```
public DatabaseTableDay createDay(String name, float weight, Long id) {

    DatabaseTableDay dayToReturn;
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_DAY_NAME, name);
    values.put(DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_DAY_WEIGHT, weight);
    values.put(DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_DAY_ID, id);

    long resID = mDatabase.insert(DatabaseHelper.TABLE_DAYS, null, values);
    if (resID == -1)
    {
       // something went wrong, do error handling here
       dayToReturn = null;
    }
    else
    {
        // no error: resID is "the row ID of the newly inserted row"
        // you only need this info if you are using autoincrement 
        // not if you set the ID yourself

        // all right, this will work -
        // but somehow it hurts a little to retrieve an entry I just added.
        // I'd like much more to simply use a constructor with all the values 
        // and create a new DatabaseTableDay instance
        dayToReturn = getDayById(id);
    }     

    return dayToReturn;
}
```

See also this link to documentation for [SQLiteDatabase insert()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#insert(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues))

Comment: It works perfectly! However, I have one more question, I download some data from web and want to put them into SQLite. Is it very bad solution to not implement multiple tables and put everything in one table `DatabaseTableDay` with Json value? I mean do have String with Json from `object` instead of List od `object`

Comment: @barmi I'm very sorry but I do not have that much experience with JSON. Having said that, maybe you will save time/ code/ work on one end (inserting data) only to end up with more of that on the other (retrieving information). I think you should ask a new question with a small example (maybe also on CodeReview) because it's about which design is better and why. The answer will depend very much on what kind of information you want to retrieve from the database.