# Listview Click Error

Tags: android, android-sqlite

When I click on a list Item in listview. The app crashes and I get this error. How can I solve it or why is the error occurring?

```
10-18 13:35:03.029 11283-11283/com.example.sebastian.dblist E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.sebastian.dblist, PID: 11283
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.sebastian.dblist/com.example.sebastian.dblist.DisplayContact}: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
Caused by: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
  at android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java:460)
  at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:136)
  at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:50)
  at com.example.sebastian.dblist.DisplayContact.onCreate(DisplayContact.java:63)
  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: What we can say? Your error says all things

Comment: this is your SQLite database exception

Comment: the error means you don't have  data in cursor to fetch.

Comment: Because the size of the Cursor object is 0. So make sure whenever you deal with Cursors, ALWAYS check for null and check for moveToFirst() without fail.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10244222/android-database-cursorindexoutofboundsexception-index-0-requested-with-a-size

Comment: You could start by providing us with some code. A [mcve] would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is your SQLite database exception

```
Caused by: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
```

I think you are trying to get data from empty table

Answer (score 0):

You are reading some data from database when click is performed on your listview.But there is no proper data which means `cusor.next()` return false.
But you force to read by this `Cusor` and it finally result in an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.